# It is possible to use the ARCore to track images like Vuforia?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

I've been checking the ARCore documentation and I did not find anything to track images like Vuforia. Does anybody known if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

ARCore is NOT a computer vision software. You would have to use something like OpenCV. ARCore is focused on mapping and tracking your world. It is not learning new patterns etc. 
So you can use computer vision (different set of tools) in your ARCore app but ARCore itself does not provide such functionalities

Comment: I couldn't find a library on top of OpenCV that could track images just like how Vuforia does

Answer (score 0):

**ARCore 1.2 brought Augmented Images API for AR apps developers. This great feature enables Android AR apps to detect and track images like Vuforia does**.

Here's what Google says about it:

> **`Augmented Images`** feature in ARCore 1.2 and higher lets you build AR apps that can respond to 2D images, such as posters or product packaging, in the user's environment. You provide a set of reference images, and ARCore tracking tells you where those images are physically located in an AR session, once they are detected in the camera view. ARCore can `track up to 20 images simultaneously` in the environment, but it cannot track multiple instances of the same image.
>   The physical image in the environment must be at least `15cm`x`15cm` and **must be flat** (for example, not wrinkled or wrapped around a bottle). Augmented Images supports `PNG` and `JPEG` file formats. The image's resolution should be at least `300`x`300` pixels.
>
> Once tracked, ARCore provides estimates for position, orientation, and physical size. These estimates are continuously refined as ARCore gathers more data. But ARCore cannot track a moving image, but it can resume tracking that image after it stops moving. All tracking happens on the device, so no internet connection is required. Reference images can be updated on-device or over the network without requiring an app update.

Hope this helps.